# Price auto update on option change in opencart using jquery

Tags: jquery, opencart, product

I have to modify the opencart shop system a bit to get a product price updated automatically, so I found a script which I've modified a bit but running into a problem right now.

Original price fetched from a div, getting updated with the values from a selected radio or select option.
But when I have more than one option in the product (multiple selects or radios) the price is not getting updated accordingly: always fetching the original price (as from the script) and when changing another option its not updating it with the updated price before.
Besides that: when you select one option, then another and changing the first option again it's not changing anything at all again.

Jquery Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.option').change(function() {
   var OriginalPrice = $('#thisIsOriginal').text();
   OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.replace( /,/,"." );
   
   var OriginalCurrency = OriginalPrice.substring(OriginalPrice.length - 1, OriginalPrice.length);
   OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.substring(0,OriginalPrice.length - 1);

   if($('.option :checked').val()) {
    var newPriceValue = $('.option :checked').attr("id");
    newPriceValue = $("label[for='" + newPriceValue + "']").text();
   }
   if($('.option :selected').val()) {
    var newPriceValue = $('.option :selected').text();
   }

   newPriceValue = newPriceValue.replace( /,/,"." );
   
   var position1 = newPriceValue.indexOf("(");
   var position2 = newPriceValue.indexOf(")");
   position1 = position1+2;
  
   var finalPriceValue = newPriceValue.substring(position1, position2);
   if(newPriceValue.indexOf('.') == -1)
   {
    finalPriceValue = "0";
   }
   else
   {
    finalPriceValue = finalPriceValue.substring(0,finalPriceValue.length - 1);
   }
   console.log(finalPriceValue);
   
   finalPriceValue = parseFloat(finalPriceValue) + parseFloat(OriginalPrice);
   finalPriceValue = finalPriceValue.toFixed(2);
   finalPriceValue = finalPriceValue.replace( ".","," );

   $('#priceUpdate').text(finalPriceValue + OriginalCurrency);
   });
});
```

The price is in Euro, so it's converting it to the correct decimal value and back.

Comment: From the looks of it, that code is to simply change the price from one to another based on the option, not a running total of all options and a base price

Comment: Thats exactly the point where I have some kind of logic problem to get this sorted out for myself :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I used to get the option price change working.
Additionally there's the option to get the product picture changed aswell.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//total value
var total = 0;

//get the original price and convert to decimal (Euro prices)
var OriginalPrice = $('#thisIsOriginal').text();
OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.replace( /,/,"." );

//get the currency (in Euro placed at the end of the string)
var OriginalCurrency = OriginalPrice.substring(OriginalPrice.length - 1, OriginalPrice.length);
OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.substring(0,OriginalPrice.length - 1);

function calcTotal() {
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        var value1 = $(this).attr("id");
        value1 = $("label[for='" + value1 + "']").text();
        value1 = value1.replace( /,/,"." );

        var position11 = value1.indexOf("(");
        var position12 = value1.indexOf(")");
        position11 = position11+2;

        var newPrice1 = value1.substring(position11, position12);
        if(value1.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            newPrice1 = "0";
        }
        else {
            newPrice1 = newPrice1.substring(0,newPrice1.length - 1);
        }

        total += parseFloat(newPrice1);
    });

    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        var value2 = $(this).text();
        value2 = value2.replace( /,/,"." );

        var position21 = value2.indexOf("(");
        var position22 = value2.indexOf(")");
        position21 = position21+2;

        var newPrice2 = value2.substring(position21, position22);
        if(value2.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            newPrice2 = "0";
        }
        else {
            newPrice2 = newPrice2.substring(0,newPrice2.length - 1);
        }

        total += parseFloat(newPrice2);
    });
}

function imageUpdate( getoptionId ) {
    var value3 = $("label[for='option-value-" + getoptionId + "']").children("img").attr("src");

    var fileNameIndex = value3.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var fileName = value3.substr(fileNameIndex);

    var fileTypeStart = fileName.indexOf("50x50");
    var fileTypeEnd = fileName.indexOf("50x50")+5;
    var fileType = fileName.substring(fileTypeEnd,fileName.length);

    var plainFileName = fileName.substring(0,fileTypeStart-1);

    var fullPath = value3.indexOf(fileName);
    fullPath = value3.substring(0,fullPath);

    var newPath = fullPath.replace("cache/","");

    var newFile = newPath + plainFileName + fileType;

    $("#imageUpdate > img").attr("src",newFile);
    $("#imageUpdate > img").attr({ width: '228px', height: '228px' });
}

$('.option').change(function() {
    total = 0;
    calcTotal();

    //add the collected changed prices on top of the original price
    total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(OriginalPrice);
    total = total.toFixed(2);
    total = total.replace( ".","," );

    //update the price value into the related div
    $('#priceUpdate').text('<span class="price-currency">' + OriginalCurrency + '</span> ' + total);

    var optionId = $(this).find("input:checked").val();
    imageUpdate(optionId);
});

});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume other parts of your code is doing as intended (as I can't see example of your html). Also going to assume all your radio  tags and select  tags have class="option" added to them.

At the moment you're checking if every .option is selected or checked but only get one value when there may be multiple values.

```
function get_final_price_value(newPriceValue)
{
  newPriceValue = newPriceValue.replace( /,/,"." );

   var position1 = newPriceValue.indexOf("(");
   var position2 = newPriceValue.indexOf(")");
   position1 = position1+2;

   var finalPriceValue = newPriceValue.substring(position1, position2);
   if(newPriceValue.indexOf('.') == -1)
   {
    finalPriceValue = "0";
   }
   else
   {
    finalPriceValue = finalPriceValue.substring(0,finalPriceValue.length - 1);
   }

  return parseFloat(finalPriceValue)
}

var runningTotalUpdatedPrice = parseFloat(OriginalPrice);

$('.option :checked').each(function(index) {
    var newPriceValue = $(this).attr("id");
    newPriceValue = $("label[for='" + newPriceValue + "']").text();
    var finalPriceValue = get_final_price_value(newPriceValue);
    runningTotalUpdatedPrice = runningTotalUpdatedPrice + finalPriceValue;
});
$('.option :selected').each(function(index) {
    var newPriceValue = $(this).text();
    var finalPriceValue = get_final_price_value(newPriceValue);
    runningTotalUpdatedPrice = runningTotalUpdatedPrice + finalPriceValue;
});

runningTotalUpdatedPrice = runningTotalUpdatedPrice.toFixed(2);
runningTotalUpdatedPrice = runningTotalUpdatedPrice.replace( ".","," );

$('#priceUpdate').text(runningTotalUpdatedPrice + OriginalCurrency);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I already got it working by completely rewriting the code, similar to your example, so we had the same idea :)
I've also added an image change function to change the product image to whatever image is set for the selected option.

I think this is very usefull for OpenCart as there are only commercial solutions out there.

Comment: Hi @BenG, would you mind answering your original question with your fix so that this question proves useful to other members of Stack Overflow please? You can then mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_final_price_value(newPriceValue)
{

var position1 = newPriceValue.indexOf("(");
var position2 = newPriceValue.indexOf(")");

position1 = position1+2;

var finalPriceValue = newPriceValue.substring(position1, position2);

if(newPriceValue.indexOf('.') == -1)
{
 finalPriceValue = "0";

}
else
{
 finalPriceValue = finalPriceValue.substring(1,finalPriceValue.length - 1 );
}


 return finalPriceValue;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.option').live('change',function() {
var OriginalPrice = $('#thisIsOriginal').text();
var OriginalCurrency = OriginalPrice.substring(0, 1);
OriginalPrice = OriginalPrice.substring(1);

var runningTotalUpdatedPrice = parseFloat(OriginalPrice);


$('.option :selected').each(function(index) {
    var newPriceValue = $(this).text();

    var finalPriceValue = get_final_price_value(newPriceValue);


    runningTotalUpdatedPrice = runningTotalUpdatedPrice +     parseFloat(finalPriceValue);
        });

 runningTotalUpdatedPrice = runningTotalUpdatedPrice.toFixed(2);

 $('#priceUpdate').text(OriginalCurrency + runningTotalUpdatedPrice  );

    }); 
 });
 </script>
```

for uk only